# Kafka doesn't recognize topics although they are in \tmp\kafka-logs

Tags: apache-kafka

I started a kafka broker on my computer. I also ran zookeeper. Once i was playing with the commands to see consumer groups or so like, suddenly kafka got time out exception. When i restarted it, all the topics were gone (i mean i couldn't get them or watch them through command line). But when i checked the kafka-logs dir, they were all there. I also created a new topic and it was shown in cmd and interestingly it's log  was near other topic logs that faced the problem mentioned. Any idea? I appreciate that.

Comment: Restarted what? Kafka, Zookeeper, or your computer? Kafka has a topic retention time, but broker restarts don't remove topics... Restarting your computer will delete all the data in /tmp, so you shouldn't keep data there anyway

Comment: I restarted kafka and zookeeper both.